# re-point LM to a new vCenter (share same database)

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

1)

I'm planning to create a new vCenter server which database point to the same db as current vCenter (the one LM pointing to atm),

Then I'm planning to repoint the LM to a new vCenter, ( the new one will see the same esx host, datastore, etc)

Is LM will be okay if I do this?

2)

The currect VC is a dediated server and a new vCenter will be VM, the current vCenter has database installed on local machine (inc update manager as well)

I'm planning to move the local db to cluster db then point the current vCenter to this new cluster and make sure everything is working before promote a new one.

Update manager will also has it own VM and point to a new db cluster.

Is anythingelse I miss out or need to pay more attention on?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you backup the DB and you have the correct installation media for the existing vCenter installation to go with the DB, you should always be able to get back to a working vCenter.

We made the same move a few years ago and have no problems.

Don't forget to update your ODBC connection to point to the new database server.

Re: Update Manager, I think it used to be a little bit flaky when it came to moving databases or reinstalling UM against an existing database so just watch that.  Worst case, you'll have to get the updates into the repository again so more time than anything.